# How do i Round Values Properly in Java?

Tags: java, math, rounding

I want to get the round values as shown below.

```
round (1.4) = 1
round (1.5) = 1
round (1.6) = 2
```

How do i get result of round (1.5) to 1 instead of 2 using java code?

Comment: You're contradiction yourself. Do you want `round (1.5)` to return 1? Or do you want it to "return 2 instead of 1"?

Comment: What about `1.59`? Exactly what causes values to round up? As posted, something like `Math.round(x-0.1);` where `x` is any of your three values yields your described results.

Comment: 1.59 should be 1. If it reached to 1.6 then move forward to 2.

Comment: I don't recommend that test case. Whatever it returns it will be fine. I want to do check only the first decimal place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want from `.6` it will be ceiling the value then use this

```
x = Math.floor(x + 0.4);
```

Comment: Perfect solution. But it requires casting into integer.

Comment: @Andreas Can you check here https://onlinegdb.com/ryUs-f79I , OP want 1.59 round to 1.

Comment: If you want as integer you have to cast.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can subtract `0.1` before calling `Math.round`. Like,

```
DoubleStream.of(1.4, 1.5, 1.59, 1.6)
        .mapToInt(x -> (int) Math.round(x - 0.1))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
1
1
1
2
```